# autocomplete not display string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

**What I am trying to achieve:** When a user finishes typing in their postcode autocomplete will show all of the possible addresses that are valid.

**How I am trying to do this:** As the user enters their postcode, 6 or 7 characters, after a second delay in their typing, autocomplete will call the AJAX function which will return the JSON, which will be translated for autocomplete to display client side.

**Problems:** I am not getting anything displayed on the browser, and unhelpfully I can only call the api 20 times per day, below is a sample of the JSON that is returned.

The JSON I am interested in that is returned is a string array Addresses, not the longitude and latitude. The other examples and questions I have seen that are similar to this have a key and value structure in their JSON for easy mapping.

**Question:** How can I get the addresses returned from the AJAX call to display in the autocomplete drop down? I can spew them out into a div but autocomplete doesn't seem to acknowledge anything. I have included the necessary resources: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css and https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

**JSON from AJAX:** - trimmed results because there are a lot:

```
{  
   "Latitude":51.991799,
   "Longitude":-1.078074,
   "Addresses":[  
      "1 Stable Close, , , , Finmere, Buckingham, Buckinghamshire",
      "10 Stable Close, , , , Finmere, Buckingham, Buckinghamshire",
      "12 Stable Close, , , , Finmere, Buckingham, Buckinghamshire",
      "14 Stable Close, , , , Finmere, Buckingham, Buckinghamshire",
      "16 Stable Close, , , , Finmere, Buckingham, Buckinghamshire"
   ]
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var typingTimer; //timer identifier
var typingInterval = 2000; // 2 second delay
var pc = $('#pcode');
var divArray = $('#out4');

//on keyup, start the countdown
pc.keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  if (pc.val) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      postcodeDelay();
    }, typingInterval);
  }
});

function postcodeDelay() {
  apiurl = 'https://api.getAddress.io/v2/uk/' + String(pc.val()) + '?api-key=key';
  // ajax call to the api too get JSON object of addresses that match the postcode entered
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiurl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: possiblePostcodes
  });
}

function possiblePostcodes(data) {

  pc.autocomplete({
    source: data.Addresses
  });
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="pcode">Enter a Postcode:</label>
  <input id="pcode" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
      label: item.Addresses // picks the array from the JSON object.
}
```

One hint: in the browser developer tools, you can select your call to the service and save the response as a JSON file. You could then set up a webserver and serve it from there, so you'd get around the 20 calls/day limit for developing.

Comment: Thanks, I got the JSON returning correctly a different way, however I still can't get autocomplete to work with the string array.